# Application runs fine on its own, segmentation faults when running GDB

Tags: c, gdb, cross-platform

I have a C application which is compiled to run on redhat linux architecture, which runs just fine during normal execution. However, as soon as I start trying to debug it using GDB, it crashes: `Child terminated with signal = 0xb (SIGSEGV).`

The thing is that there are some caveats here - it is a linux application, but I am debugging remotely using gdbserver from a windows machine. I followed the steps in this article: https://www.linux.com/news/remote-cross-target-debugging-gdb-and-gdbserver, which basically state that I need to compile a cross-platform version of GDB that will run on Windows but can debug Linux applications.  I have done this. The application is running inside a docker container on my local machine at which point I have run gdbserver on the container. I have created the cross-platform GDB executable and I am running it, connecting to the gdbserver on the docker container.

It can attach the breakpoints meaning it is finding the symbols just fine, yet as soon as the application starts doing anything, it crashes due to segfault.

The thing here is that I know it's somehow related to the cross-platform-ness of the GDB executable. If I run the regular GDB from the Windows Subsystem for Linux and connect to the gdbserver using that, it works just fine, yet the cross-platform compiled GDB causes segfaults. So, does anyone have any clues about what I might be able to do about this?

The whole point of doing this is to be able to debug using an IDE (preferably VSCode) which is why I need to use the cross-platform GDB executable and can't just use the Windows Subsystem for Linux GDB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a program runs under A but crashes under B, it means that it has a bug causing undefined behavior. That's it, it is not about GDB but about your code.

Comment: There is a contradiction too - if it "runs fine" why the debugger?

Comment: If all you want is to run GDB through an IDE, you could just use a native Linux IDE.  I think VSCode itself even has a native Linux version as it is based off of Code Composer Studio (which itself might be Eclipse-based?  It's been awhile since I immersed myself in the world of IDEs)

Comment: @Eugene The program works when GDB is not being run. The program works when GDB is being run from a Linux architecture. The program does not work when GDB is being run from a Windows architecture. Perhaps there is a bug, but what could possibly be different about these GDB builds that could trigger such a bug? Ironically I cannot use the debugger to find such a bug.

Comment: Can you get a backtrace after it segfaults?  Is it GDB itself that is segfaulting rather than program being debugged?

Comment: Like @EugeneSh. said, this almost certainly isn't an issue with GDB, but your program. We'll need to see the specific code that seg faults. Undefined behavior is exactly that. Could work in some instances, not in others. It's undefined.

Comment: *"I know it's somehow related to the cross-platform-ness"* - No, you don't. UB can manifest itself in many ways. Including working as intended.

Comment: Looking at the core dump, and nothing obviously sticks out at me as being the cause of the segfault here. I am starting to think that, perhaps it will be easier to convince my corporate overlords to let me use an unapproved Linux machine on the corporate network (so I can use a native Linux IDE @Christian), than it will be to solve this debugging mess.

Comment: It is always the program. Gdb  is used by millions of programmers. Probably when gdb is active your program is run from different addresses and one of your out of bounds or dangling pointers are in the protected memory area.

Comment: @AlexA Using a different machine that doesn't segfault won't actually fix the problem.You cannot assume the program will still function in the future just because it functions now. (again, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

Comment: I am voting to close as off topic since the OP has not provided a minimum, reproducible example.

Comment: I will never in a million years be able to do such a thing, as I have no clue what is the cause here, so I would not able to provide a reproducible example. So if you want to close it, go ahead. My C application has around 2 million lines of code, and the stack trace in the core dump isn't providing anything helpful in this case.

Comment: From your question it is even not clear what is crashing. Your program? GDB? Something else? Can you post the exact terminal session transcript?

Comment: The actual application is crashing - gdbserver then terminates, causing the remote gdb session to end. The only (unexpected) output I get is `Child terminated with signal = 0xb (SIGSEGV)`, which is output by gdbserver indicating that the underlying application has terminated. There is no other output to provide.

Comment: Well, I guess `gdbserver` should not be crashing because of the debugged program. If it does then it could be it's bug. Does it work with some simple bug-free program such as "hello world" ?

Comment: Actually no, my mistake in the previous comment. `gdbserver` *should* terminate once the debugged process is terminated unless it is executed with specific  command line option (`--multi`) as stated [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html)

Comment: Since you already use docker, try running the application with valgrind or some other memory debugger you're comfortable with. This might give more of a clue than poking around with gdb.

Comment: Along with Olaf's comment - It sounds like it's worth investigating other means of debugging.  If you're app is 2Million+ lines of code, surely it's under some sore of version control - may be worth trying a few changesets (or git bisect or equivalent) to see if you can find when/where the problem was introduced.